# Hardware driver for LinuxCNC

Tags: hardware

Is it possible to create a hardware driver for LinuxCNC on a Raspberry Pi without violating the hardware design philosophy of LinuxCNC ([stated here](http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?HardwareDesign))?

If yes, could this driver make use of any existing library like pigpio?

I'm not a programmer. So my question is just to get clear the possibilities of using LinuxCNC on a Pi.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, it is possible, to create a driver along the lines of pigpio, but HW-drivers need to be in the RT-part of the HAL system, so they are loadable Kernel modules or realtime threads. User space libraries are inappropriate for that, since the loading mechanism of the Kernel has special naming conventions to initialize and unload modules and register tasks.

However, studying the library can help.
By combining the Kernel mechanics of the parport-driver with the register/memory handling of pigpio, one can probably begin.

I do believe, that the LinuxCNC hardware design philosophy is satisfied by this approach, because no other hardware than protection and level shifting is required with directly driving/reading the pins in a realtime task.